# Why we choose the least square estimator than another one in regression model?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear

If we have the linear model $Y_i-\bar{Y} =b(X_i - \bar{X}) + \varepsilon_i,\ i=1,..., n$ ,  then we can find easily an unbiased estimator $b^*$ for $b$ with the least squares method. If $c=(Y_n - \bar{Y})/(X_n - \bar{X})$ is another unbiased estimator, then which one is better to choose? I believe that the least squares estimator is better for the linear model because it minimizes the distance of the observations $Y_i - \bar{Y}$ from  regression line, which means that the SSE is smaller. Therefore the SSR is closer to SST, and that means that $R^2$ is closer to 1, which I know is not always what we want, however I believe that it could be one reason that $b^*$  is more preferable than $c$.

Is my thought correct, and if it is, is there any other reason why we choose $b^*$ than $c$, and if it is false, can someone explain why?

Comment: $Yn = n $ times $Y$ or $Y_n$? $Xn$?  What does "the SSR is closer to SST" mean? Assume SSE is sum of square of residual, SSR = sum of square of model (regression) and SST = total sum of square.

Comment: Is $Y_n$ intended to be the largest $Y$, the $Y$ that goes with the largest $X$, or simply the last $Y$ in a list -- presumably just be some random observation? I'd suggest you compare not the $R^2$ but the variance of the two estimators of the slope$

Comment: @a_stastician By Yn I mean just the n-th observation . When I say is  closer to SST , I mean while the SSE is smaller  and SST is constant we have that SSR is larger so SSR is ''closer'' to SST .

Comment: @Glen_b Y_n is the n-th observation if we think that we have n observation of a variable  (maybe I would make it a little confusing now but in my question I wrote Y as the sum of Y_i divided by n, not the variable Y) . So for your answer , it would be better if the variance is smaller because if for example is significant smaller than the  variance of c  it would more likely reject the null hypothesis (b=0)  with a t-statistical test ? Thank you both for your time !

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying there; I wasn't talking about significance at all, merely precision. Conventionally one would write the random variable representing the average of the variables $Y_1$... $Y_n$ as $\bar{Y}$

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find how to write $\bar{Y}$ that's why I wrote it this way . I would fix that .  You told me that is better to compare the variance of the two estimators  and I was trying to think why this would help to choose one . So one thing that I thought was that if the variance of the estimator c is substantial smaller for example , it would probably has a smaller p-value at the t-test . However then I remember that the least square estimator has the least variance of all estimator that are linear combination of Y_i . What was your thought about comparing the variances?